# Notable academics or departments ranking list?

Tags: research-process, university

Is there anything like a directory or list of notable leading living figures based on subject area or research concentration?

Comment: Sure: [Microsoft Academic Search](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/).

Comment: @JonathanLandrum: Within limits (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/how-does-microsoft-academic-search-generate-its-rankings).

Comment: Sure: Wikipedia.

Comment: thanks for the feedback Microsoft Academic Search is indeed what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think the American Academy of Arts and Sciences might be a good place to start, at least if your focus is primarily on academics in the U.S. Two criticisms of the academy: it tends to be clique-y. Harvard is always going to have the most new fellows every year because they've already got the most fellows. Second, not everybody who deserves to be a member is one. They're really good about not giving memberships to people who *don't* deserve them (at least in my field, Philosophy), but there are some people who clearly should be members but aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Another online resource (although last updated in 2008) is the list of ISI highly cited researchers at http://highlycited.com/browse/.

A google search returns also this "preliminary" [list](http://community.thomsonreuters.com/t5/InCites-Customer-Forum/Preliminary-publication-of-new-lists-of-Highly-Cited-Researchers/td-p/36685) from December 2013.

Comment: Interesting that Noam Chomsky is not on their list, even though he is "cited within the field of Arts and Humanities more often than any other living scholar between 1980 and 1992" (Wikipedia).

Comment: Had a look at the highlycited site sounds interesting,thanks for the info